# Trying to find the number of swaps it would take to sort in ascending order an unordered array

Tags: java, sorting

Here's what I've got. I am having trouble with getting counter to increment.

```
                if(OutputArray[y] != TestArray[y]){
                int value = TestArray[y];
                int index = a.Search(OutputArray, ArrayLength, value); 
                System.out.println(index);
                int temp = OutputArray[y];
                //OutputArray[y] = TestArray[index];
                //OutputArray[index] = temp;
                counter++;
            }
```

This is the other method. I am using this to get the index of where the Array index from the TestArray can be found in the OutputArray.

```
    for (int z = 0; z < ArrayLength; z++)
            {
               //Returns index of element if found
                if (OutputArray[z] == value)
                    toReturn=z;

            }  
        return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Please follow the Java naming convention of `camelCase` for variable names and methods, not `UpperCase`. It makes it clear what is a class and what isn't, and doesn't confuse the syntax highlighter here on SO.

Comment: You haven’t given us enough information for us to help you.  Is counter a local variable?  A class member?  A static?  What is `a`?  It seems to have a method `Search`, but what it is we can’t tell.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: indentation please